# Dynamic constants within AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

For anyone with deeper knowledge of [constants](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#constant) is it possible to somehow assign it dynamically?

I know this is a silly question but up to this point I have been using a constant to define a parameter:

```
myApp.constant('Groupid', 10);
```

While this works fine in development in production this parameter will change based on the group. Luckily this can be determined before, at, or during module initialization.

So, I was thinking something that would be able to set this parameter in the `.run()` or `.config()` operation or just `.constant('Groupid', function(){})`. But the latter doesn't work becuase `constant` only accepts a [value](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant)/[object](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#constant) as its second argument.

As the only alternative that can see I could use a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#directive) but it would be evaluated way too many times unnecessarily between all service calls. While it is a fairly light and static function but still to be called so many times... I'd prefer a constant assignment.

Is that just something I have to live with for the time being or there is light at the end of the tunnel?

#### In Addition

Just as I posted this question another idea came to mind. Is it possible to pass in a custom value/object from outside into `.module`?

```
var cusObj = { GroupId: getGroupId(), };
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'ngResource', 'cusObj']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A decorator can modify or encapsulate other providers. There is one exception and that a **constant cannot be decorated.** so you can use `value` from `angular`.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.value('movieTitle', 'The Matrix');

app.config(function ($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('movieTitle', function ($delegate) {
    return $delegate + ' - starring Keanu Reeves';
  });
});

app.controller('MyController', function (movieTitle) {
  expect(movieTitle).toEqual('The Matrix - starring Keanu Reeves');
});
```

Comment: Strange I seems to be having difficulty getting this to work with ``ui.router resolve`` property. I need to do a bit more testing with this.

Comment: OK, the cause seems to be resolved. Typo on my side. Thank you very much that certainly did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Providers allow complex creation function and configuration options. A provider is actually a configurable factory. The provider accepts an object or a constructor.
You can read about all the options [here](https://gist.github.com/demisx/9605099)

```
app.provider('movie', function () {
    var version;
    return {
        setVersion: function (value) {
            version = value;
        },
        $get: function () {
            return {
                title: 'The Matrix' + ' ' + version
            }
        }
    }
});

app.config(function (movieProvider) {
    movieProvider.setVersion('Reloaded');
});
```

Comment: Certainly that looks like it will also do the trick. Thanks for the info and link to a very good post.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the accepted answer I'd like to share my own use case, setting a value based on the `$window.location.origin`. In my app, I need to prefix an ID returned from the server with this base URL value, so that the resultant link `${base_url}/${id}` works in both development and production environments.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.config(function ($provide, $windowProvider) {
  var $window = $windowProvider.$get();
  $provide.value('originUrl', $window.location.origin);
  // `originUrl` is set according to the server
  // that has served up the code
});

app.controller('MyController', function (originUrl) {
  expect(originUrl).toEqual('http://localhost:8080'); // e.g. for development
  expect(originUrl).toEqual('http://mysuperapp.com'); // e.g. for production
});
```

Comment: That look interesting. Will give it a shot when I get a good use case for this.